# @Before and @After not working with JUnit 5 on Eclipse 2018-12 JAVA

Tags: java, testcase, junit5, test-suite

I just created a test class from File->New->JUnit Test Cases and this is my whole code:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class TestingJUnit {

@Before
public void testOpenBrowser() {
    System.out.println("Opening Chrome browser");
}

@Test
public void tesingNavigation() {
    System.out.println("Opening website");
}

@Test
public void testLoginDetails() {
    System.out.println("Enter Login details");
}

@After
public void testClosingBrowser() {
    System.out.println("Closing Google Chrome browser");
}
}
```

But when I run this cas only **@Test** annotations are running **@Before** and **@After** annotations code are not running. Please guide me I think this is JUnit version or eclipse IDE version problem, and also my all Test classes not running in **TestSuit** I don't know why although Test Classes are running fine individually.
My TestSuit Class is here:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({TestingJUnit.class, SecondTest.class})
public class TestSuit {

}
```

Comment: see https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/ and use `@BeforeEach`

Comment: `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` is woking fine now. I am checking JUnit 5 User Guide. Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try using `@BeforeEach` instead of `@Before` and `@AfterEach` instead of `@After`

Comment: Yes this is working but what about TestSuite?? TestSuit class not executing all classes

Comment: Add this `public class FeatureTestSuite {
  // the class remains empty,
  // used only as a holder for the above annotations
}` check here for more info https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Aggregating-tests-in-suites

Comment: Yes but this is for JUnit 4 and I am working on JUnit 5

Comment: For TestSuit in Junit 5 you need to  use `@SelectPackages("packageName")` or `@SelectClasses( TestingJUnit.class )`

Answer (score 0):

Try Using This

```
@BeforeEach
public void before() {
    System.out.println("Before");
}

@AfterEach
public void after() {
    System.out.println("After");
}

@Test
public void sum_with3numbers() {
    System.out.println("Test 1");
}

@Test
public void sum_with1numbers() {
    System.out.println("Test 2");
}
```

Output will be:

```
Before
Test 1
After
Before
Test 2
After
```